# When I click the last image that I selected is submitting too jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload

My file input form have any multiple in it.  Its working fine when I choose an image and click the submit.  But the problem is when I choose an image and click browse image again and click the button it ending two image the first image that selected and the new image.  The same as changing image a multiple times then click the button

Comment: It's very hard for us to pin point the problem without seeing your code, so please include your HTML, jQuery and other relevant information

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I tried to edit the text but it was not clear English at all